# If I’d had more time, I could have finished everything

Tags: word-usage

Consider this sentence

> If I’d had more time, I could have finished everything.

I am aware that "could have" could be used in a hypothetical situation, e.g. imaginary past. Although I don't known whether the apostrophe in `apostrophe + d` represents "could", "should", "would" or have, could someone please give a hint? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think in truly relaxed natural conversational context, most speakers wouldn't bother trying to articulate the Past **Perfect** here - they'd probably just go with Simple Past ***If I had** more time, I could've [blah blah]*. Certainly not many Brits would feel the need to go all-out with ***If I would have had** more time...*

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Would I have (had) vs If I would have (had) and Had I vs If I had](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/123792/would-i-have-had-vs-if-i-would-have-had-and-had-i-vs-if-i-had)

Comment: There are almost no situations where _'d_ is ambiguous.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's from the verb 'to have' and is an abbreviated version of the past tense *I had*. 
"If I had had more time..."

> "*Today*, if *I had* more time, I could finish everything".
>
> "Yesterday, if *I had had* more time (or if *I'd had* more time), I
>   could *have* finished everything."

To make your life more difficult, we also use "I'd" for "I would".

> "If the children did that I'd shout at them."
>
> "I'd keep away from there if I were you."

*Could* and *should* are never abbreviated that way.

The context tells you whether the verb is *had* or *would*.

This example contains "I'd" twice:

> "If I'd had more time I'd have finished everything."

It means "If **I had** had more time **I would** have finished everything."

Comment: I think that was what it was before (*I'd* was *not* a contraction for *I should*). But Merriam-Webster and Lexico include "I had", "I would", and "I should" as possible terms that can be contracted to *I'd*. Cambridge and Collins don't mention "I should".

Comment: @AIQ Interesting. I can't remember hearing "I'd" and knowing that it meant "I should". Have you an example handy?

Comment: Absolutely not. I have never seen anyone use that contraction for "I should". But seeing it in MW makes me wonder if it's a new usage.

Comment: In such contexts, I think ***should*** is just a less common / outmoded alternative to ***would*** (which itself is often replaced by ***had*** anyway, regardless of what some grammarians think of constructions like [*If I **had have** lost you, I don't know what I'd do.*](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/62490/2637)